# angular 7 not able to read public variable in http callback

Tags: http, callback, angular7

I'm using angular 7 in my project. My problem is i can't able to get the public variable in http function callback.

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
      public isFlag:boolean = false;

      constructor() { }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.getData();
      }

      getData() {
        let url = '/login.aspx';
        this.testService.getDetails(url).subscribe(
            (data) => {
            console.log('Success : ' + JSON.stringify(data));
            this.isFlag = true; // 'isFlag' variable is not in 'this' keyword. Service callback is return successfully.
        },
            (err) => { console.log('Error : ' + err); }
        );
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try This:

```
data: any = null;
public isFlag: boolean = false;

constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.getData();
}

getData() {
 let url = '/login.aspx';
 this.testService.getDetails(url).subscribe(
  res => { this.data = res },
  err => console.log(err),
  () => this.checkResponse(this.data)
 );
}

checkResponse(data) {
 console.log('Success : ' + JSON.stringify(data));
 this.isFlag = true;
}
```

Hope So its solve your problem!